# Understanding wavefunctional form of lowering operator for a scalar CFT

Tags: conformal-field-theory

In his book (String Theory Volume 1, pp. 66-68), Polchinski explains state-operator correspondence and derives the vacuum state through the identity operator:

$$
\Psi_1[X_b] \propto \exp \left( -\frac{1}{\alpha'} \right) \sum_{m=1}^\infty m X_m X_{-m} \tag{2.8.24}
$$

where $X_m$ comes from the expansion of the field at the boundary:
$$
X_b(\theta) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} X_n e^{in\theta} \tag{2.8.19}
$$
or in terms of holomorphic/antiholomorphic coordinates:
$$
X_b(z, \bar{z}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( z^n X_n + \bar{z}^n X_{-n} \right).
$$

He then states that the $\alpha_{m}$ operator, which was defined previously as:
$$\label{eq:alpha}
\alpha_{m} = \left(\frac{2}{\alpha'}\right)^{1/2} \oint \frac{dz}{2 \pi} z^{m} \partial X(z) \tag{2.7.2a}
$$
acts on the wavefunctional $\Psi_1$ using the Schrödinger basis operator:
$$
\alpha_n = - \frac{i n}{(2 \alpha')^{1/2}} X_{-n} - i \left( \frac{\alpha'}{2} \right)^{1/2}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial X_n} \tag{2.8.25a}
$$
and comments that this:

> follows from the Laurent expansion at $|z| = 1$ and the mode algebra.

How can such Laurent expansion around that point be used in deriving this? And what does the derivation look like?

---

I've tried inserting $\ref{eq:alpha}$ into the path integral:
$$
\Psi[X_b] = \int \left[ d X_i\right]_{X_b} \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha'} \int d^2 z \partial X \bar{\partial} X \right) \tag{2.8.20}
$$
using field expansions:
\begin{align}
X_i & = X_{\text{cl}} + X'_i, \tag{2.8.21a} \\
X_\text{cl}(z, \bar{z}) & = X_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (z^n X_n + \bar{z}^n X_{-n}) \tag{2.8.21b}
\end{align}
but couldn't make much progress this way.

Comment: If you use 2.8.19 in 2.7.2a with $z= e^{i \theta}$, then at least I can see how to get the first term of 2.8.25a. I'm not sure about the second term though.

Comment: I actually got twice as much as the first term. The initial hope was that the second term is equal to the first term in *some* computation, but unsurprisingly the second term just cancels the first one whenever I plug it anywhere.

Comment: That's good at least that the second term cancels the first one since $\alpha_m$ should be an annihilation operator.